# How can I prevent content from disappearing under a Fixed-Header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making an *endless* page, ie. When a user scrolls to the end of the page, I load more content at the bottom (I'll be loading blog posts to be precise), this is part is finished, However.....

My employer requested that I add a sliding feature to *indicate and display* part of the new posts that have just been added. **My problem** is that the old posts(on top) are disappearing under a Fixed-Header I have on top when I *slide-up* the 'posts-container'.

Here's a clearer picture(scroll result page to the bottom please): http://jsfiddle.net/jlstr/D4BqN/

So, in summary.. Could you guys please teach me how to make a Layout(for the posts) that displays all the posts, but prevents them from disappearing under the Fixed-Header?

Thanks in advance and Best Regards!

Comment: Did you meant something like this http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/Cfyz2/. I set position absolute for the `content` div.

Comment: well.... not exactly, your code is concealing the Fixed-Header, Which should always be visible because it has all the user options. So, that's missing from your answer. Thanks for your reply sir, and my apologies for my delayed response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should scroll down automatically instead of changing the margin: http://jsfiddle.net/D4BqN/2/.

```
function $slide() {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: '+=100'
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is also more intuitive since you in fact want to scroll down to the new post. (You're currently moving up the element which places it behind the fixed header.)

Comment: Wow, so far so good, I'll try this on the real project now. I'll let you know how it turns out. Sorry for the delayed reply, I just wrote the Question as I was leaving office. :)

Comment: wonderful! That worked perfectly well ! Thank you very, very much!
Incidentally, I noticed that you slide the body element. Could you give a little insight on why is that?

Comment: @user766388: What exactly do you mean? I used scrolling the body element because that makes the page scroll down (or do you mean something else with "slide"?).

Comment: well I just thought that sliding the body element was overkill, and instead I just needed to slide a lesser div. but nevermind what I said, I'm anything but a html/css expert. Thanks for your help sir.

Comment: Hi again, I just noticed that this solution doesn't work in Firefox. I believe it has something to do with the scrollTop property(possible), do you know any work-around? Thank you once more.

Comment: @user766388: Seems like you have to scroll `html` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/D4BqN/4/. It works for me with that, but I've not encountered it before so I'm not sure if that's a bullet-proof fix...

Comment: Great, thank you once more for the fix. Fortunately works well for Firefox and Opera, wish I could know how it does on IE, but I work on Ubuntu. I can't thank you enough, for your help and your kindness. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the line

```
'margin-top': '-=100'
```

to

```
'scroll-top': '+=100'
```

in your `slide()` function should work.

Comment: Thanks, I believe it's obvious for you CSS/HTML masters. I can't thank you enough, it's amazing to learn so much in one single question.